# Finding blank records in a text file

Tags: shell

I have a text file which has data separated by delimiters. I need to run a loop which will check each row and print the row number which has blank record(s). The text file can have any number of rows.
My text file looks like this:

```
398569527JOM08021952|XIMH009|M|20150331 
398569527JOM08021952|XIMH009|M|20150331  
525230008DEF12061960|XSTAR002|M|20150331
```

So at times it can be like :

```
525230008DEF12061960|XSTAR001|      |20150331
525230008DEF12061960|XSTAR001|      |20150331 
                           |XIMH009|   |
585485743JAM08241950|         |H|20150331
```

So the output will show me that Row Number 1,2,3 and 4 has blank records.
Can anyone please help me with some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use awk to do this:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i ~ /^[[:space:]]*$/) {print NR, $0; next}}' file
1 525230008DEF12061960|XSTAR001|      |20150331
2 525230008DEF12061960|XSTAR001|      |20150331
3                            |XIMH009|   |
4 585485743JAM08241950|         |H|20150331
```

The script loops through each field, using the `|` as the field separator. If a field is empty or only contains spaces, the row number `NR` and the contents of the line `$0` are printed. `next` skips to the next row, to avoid duplicate output if there is more than one missing field.

Here's another way you can do it, using grep:

```
$ grep -E '(^|\|)[[:space:]]*(\||$)' file
```

This matches the start of the line or a `|` followed by zero or more spaces, followed by a `|` or the end of the line. You can use the `-n` switch to add the line numbers that match.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. Don't forget to accept my answer, by clicking on the tick next to it, if your problem is solved.

Comment: Please don't use the comments to add to your question. If you have a different format, you should try to adapt the code accordingly and if you have any problems, then consider asking a new question.